# Istio EnvoyFilter Lua HttpCall doesn't work with HTTPS?

Tags: https, lua, istio, envoyproxy

I need to decrypt the body of a request in an external API.
But, when I try to do it with an EnvoyFilter using lua it doesn't work.
If I try the same code that I'm posting here, but without HTTPS, works. But with HTTPS returns 503.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: eva-decrypt-filter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: ANY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.lua
          typed_config:
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
            inlineCode: |
              function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
               local buffered = request_handle:body()
               local bodyString = tostring(buffered:getBytes(0, buffered:length()))
               print("bodyString ->")
               print(bodyString)
               if string.match(bodyString, "valcirtest") then
                print("iniciando http_Call")
                local responseHeaders, responseBody = request_handle:httpCall(
                  "thirdparty",
                  {
                   [":method"] = "POST",
                   [":path"] = "/decrypt",
                   [":authority"] = "keycloack-dev-admin.eva.bot",
                   [":scheme"] = "https",
                   ["content-type"] = "application/json",
                   ["content-length"] = bodyString:len(),
                  },
                  bodyString,
                  3000)
                print("acabou a requisicao")
                print("responseHeaders -> ")
                print(responseHeaders)
                print(responseHeaders[":status"])
                print("responseBody -> ")
                print(responseBody)
                local content_length = request_handle:body():setBytes(responseBody)
                request_handle:headers():replace("content-length", content_length)
               else
                print("nao entrou")
               end
              end
    - applyTo: CLUSTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
      patch:
        operation: ADD
        value: # cluster specification
          name: thirdparty
          connect_timeout: 1.0s
          type: STRICT_DNS
          dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
          lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
          load_assignment:
            cluster_name: thirdparty
            endpoints:
              - lb_endpoints:
                  - endpoint:
                      address:
                        socket_address:
                          protocol: TCP
                          address: keycloack-dev-admin.eva.bot
                          port_value: 443
```

The response error is:

```
503
responseBody ->
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
```

I'm using Istio v.1.11.4.

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using? How did you setup HTTPS connection for your application?

Answer (score 1):

It should be configured on your "thirdparty" cluster adding the following on your cluster config:

```
transport_socket:
  name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @koffi-kodjo's answer, you also need to specify the `typed_config` property. The `transport_socket` node should be placed at the same level of the `name: thirdparty` node.

```yaml
        transport_socket:
          name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
          typed_config: 
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
```

ref:

- https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/11582#issuecomment-646427632
- https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/v3/tls.proto.html#extensions-transport-sockets-tls-v3-upstreamtlscontext